# Active Record find via parent's foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

Let me display a sketch of needed models:

1) I've a Unit model
it's connected (has a foreign key) to the Type model. has_many :People

2)Type - it's a simple model, a string 'name' - like ('first','second', etc)

3) Person model - just a person.

What i need to do's output:
each type with all the units, each with all the people of this unit

**OR**
How can i access unit's type via person record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i've solved this problem.
The query goes something like this:

```
Person.includes(units: [:type]).
order(Units.title).group_by {|p| p.unit.type}.
map {|type, v| { type=> v.group_by{|p| p.unit}
```

Sorry if i didn't describe the question properly.